# Ray-tracing a sphere with displacement mapping

Tags: graphics, geometry, raytracing

I'm interested in building a simple "Google Earth" type app (for overlaying my own information, not the huge quantity of data that Google has).  I'd like it to just be a simple X11 app that ray-traces a sphere with displacement (topographic) information.  Ray-sphere intersection is pretty simple, but when the displayment mapping is throw in there it starts to get muddy in my head.

I was wondering if there's a simple technique to extend basic ray-sphere intersection to include displacement data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I know its been 12 years since first post, but I've uploaded a complete solution to this problem here:
https://github.com/ramakarl/just_math

See the sample for math_displace_sphere. This raytraces a displaced sphere terrain at arbitrary detail w/o any mesh. Pure CPU code, could be ported to shader/GPU. MIT licensed.

The solution is to march along a ray, while projecting the ray sample points back down to lat-long, and sampling the terrain texture to determine the displaced height at that sample. Heights are specified relative to center of sphere.

Pseudo-code:

```
for ( ; ray_hgt >= terrain_hgt && ray_hgt <= shell_hgt; ) { 

        sample += ray_dir * dt; 

        ray_hgt = (sample - sphere_center).Length();

        // given sample, compute surface_pnt and lat, long
        ComputeSphereUV ( sample, surface_pnt, lat, long ); 
                
        pixel_val = terrain_map->GetPixelUV ( lat, long ).x;                                    

        terrain_hgt = sphere_radius + pixel_val * terrain_depth;    
}
```

Comment: Thank goodness you posted, my boss is furious I'm 12 years overdue on this! ;)

Comment: This is a phenomenal andd very simple answer. Totally worth the 12 years wait

Answer (score 1):

Displacement mapping is pretty easy -- just tessellate the sphere, add offsets to the vertex positions based on the altitude sampled from the maps, and ray-trace all the pieces.

How far away is the camera from the sphere/earth?  If you're right near the surface, it's probably not worth making a whole "sphere" at all, just make a "height field."  If you're far (viewing the whole planet at once), then even the tallest mountains shouldn't visibly displace the surface, so you should be using simple bump mapping instead.  Consider also using a combination -- a coarse tessellation that's truly displaced, and bump mapping on the residual height differences.

But in any case, I can't imagine why you would ray trace, as you've described the problem.  Just chop it into triangles and use OpenGL.  You probably don't need any ray-traced effects.

Comment: See my comment in response to Vuk, I'm hoping to keep the Earth represented as a sphere so the intersection calculation is as simple as possible.  OpenGL is out because a lot of the time we want to be able to run things over a network from a server and GLX tends to choke over a socket.

Answer (score 1):

I found this paper: http://www.cgl.uwaterloo.ca/~ecdfourq/GI2008/FourquetGI2008.pdf

Thought I'd share as it seems to cover exactly what I want to do, thanks guys!

Comment: Do you know of an actual implementation of this algorithm? I have an application where I'd quite like to try it.

Comment: Heyo, I'm currently trying to implement this. It's one of the goals I've set for myself as my final project for a course I'm taking (one of the authors is my prof, but he didn't do the core writing). It's proven to be painfully hard, but I'm getting close. I'm keeping progress logs on the project [over here](https://github.com/FabriceCastel/raytracer). I haven't put anything up about the height map yet because it's not done, but when I nail it (if I do) I'll post a victorious entry. So far I get the shape kinda right, the shadows are whack and the normals are completely off :|

Answer (score 0):

Well the [Ray-Tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29) process is the same no matter if you have a simple 20-poly sphere or a complex displaced 2k-poly sphere. The ray traverses the scene no matter what it contains. But it is used for achieving visual effects such as transparency, reflections, refractions, etc. and from what you said in your question I think you could go without those in your project. It is very likely that you can get away with simple low-cost [Ray-Casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting) here.

So, once you get the Rendering engine in place, you can add all the displacement you want to the scene. Two most common ways of modifying geometry are:

1. Bump mapping, and
2. Displacement mapping

**Displacement mapping** adds real polygons to existing geometry, while **bump mapping** only simulates the visual effect by bending surface normals and thus influencing shadowing of the object. And while bending normals is a far quicker and less costly operation than tessalating geometry and adding new polys, it does not produce precise shadowing results, so watch out for that if it is of any concern to your application.

Also, consider using **adaptive** [Level of Detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) algorithms and data structures, because the further away you are from the geometry the less detail it needs.

Comment: I was actually hoping that since I'm simulating the Earth, I can keep it a geometric sphere so the there's no scene traversal or multiple polygon testing.

Comment: Yeah, that dependson the context, i.e. will you only place terrain formations such as mountains on the sphere representing the Earth, or will you also need caves with holes in them, semi-transparent rivers and stuff like that which needs to be double-sided.   

What precisely do you mean when you say "no scene traversal" and "multi-poly testing"? One important question I have is - Do you plan to write the rendering engine from scratch yourself or will you use an existing one?

Comment: I'll be writing it myself.  I'm really just wanting an Earth with maybe blue marble data overlaid on it, with proper altitude information.  I don't need anything fancy like caves or transparent rivers.  I'll probably leave the water flat blue if I can actually.

Comment: Thumbs up for chosing to get your hands a little diry with implementing a renderer, you will no doubt benefit from the experience. Displacement is nothing but a few math equasions added to it and should be pretty straight forward for you.